# Regex to format IPv6 address - remove leading zeroes

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Say I have an IPv6 address like:

```
2001:04E8:0000:4001:0000:0000:0000:0000/64
```

And I want output like

```
2001:4E8:0:4001:0:0:0:0/64
```

So basically, it removes leading zeroes and at the same time, replaces four zeroes with a single zero.

```
replaceAll("(:(0)*)|(^0+)",":")
```

the above regex does the job, but gives output as

```
2001:4E8::4001::::/64
```

The four zeroes are all omitted.

Note: Input maybe ANY valid ipv6 address

Comment: Which dbms are you using? replace/regexp functionality tend to be a bit different between products.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `REPLACE` twice and `SUBSTR` to remove leading 0.

```
SELECT ipv6,
       SUBSTR(REPLACE(REPLACE(':' || ipv6, ':00', ':'),':0', ':'),2) AS result
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a8f3/2/0)**</kbd>

Demo is using `MySQL` because `Oracle` is not responding. The only change is string concatenation.

Output:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════╗
║                    ipv6                     ║           result           ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║ 2001:04E8:0000:4001:0000:0000:0000:0000/64  ║ 2001:4E8:0:4001:0:0:0:0/64 ║
║ 0000:0001:0012:0123:1234:0000:0000:0000/64  ║ 0:1:12:123:1234:0:0:0/64   ║
║ 0001:04E8:0000:4001:0000:0000:0000:0000/64  ║ 1:4E8:0:4001:0:0:0:0/64    ║
║ 0012:04E8:0000:4001:0000:0000:0000:0000/64  ║ 12:4E8:0:4001:0:0:0:0/64   ║
║ 0123:04E8:0000:4001:0000:0000:0000:0000/64  ║ 123:4E8:0:4001:0:0:0:0/64  ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample using Oracle's Regexp_Replace:

```
   SQL> with t as (
  2  select '2001:04E8:0000:4001:0000:0000:0000:0000/64' str from dual union all
  3  select '0000:0001:0012:0123:1234:0000:0000:0000/64' from dual union all
  4  select '0001:04E8:0000:4001:0000:0000:0000:0000/64' from dual union all
  5  select '0000:0001:0012:0123:1234:0000:0000:0000/64' from dual
  6  ) -- end of sample data
  7  select regexp_replace(str, '(:|^)(0{0,3})([1-9]*)', '\1\3') str
  8    from t;
STR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2001:4E8:0:4001:0:0:0:0/64
0:1:12:123:1234:0:0:0/64
1:4E8:0:4001:0:0:0:0/64
0:1:12:123:1234:0:0:0/64
```

Comment: I like this solution, only problem I see is
when input is like '2001:04E8:0000:4001:0000:0:0000:0/64'
output will be '2001:04E8:0000:4001:0::0:/64'

Answer (score 0):

In java, something like this works:

```
replaceAll("(:000)|(:0*)", ":");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT '2001:04E8:0000:4001:0000:0000:0000:0000/64' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '0000:0001:0012:0123:1234:0000:0000:0000/64' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '0001:04E8:0000:4001:0000:0000:0000:0000/64' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '0000:0001:0012:0123:1234:0000:0000:0000/64' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '2001:04E8:0000:4001:0000:0:0000:0/64' FROM dual
  )
SELECT 
    REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '(:|^)0+([[:xdigit:]]+)', '\1\2')
from t;

2001:4E8:0:4001:0:0:0:0/64
0:1:12:123:1234:0:0:0/64
1:4E8:0:4001:0:0:0:0/64
0:1:12:123:1234:0:0:0/64
2001:4E8:0:4001:0:0:0:0/64
```